# QEMU on M1 Mac shared mount permissions are incorrect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, qemu

I've recently started deving on a M1 mac, and I wanted to get a simple linux system virtualized. Multipass seemed like a great idea, until I was struggling to forward ports.

So I created a very simple qemu machine, modeled off the way multipass emulates their instances here it is:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
-machine virt,highmem=off \
-accel hvf \
-name ubuntu-qemu \
\
-cpu cortex-a72 \
-smp 4 \
\
-m 4096 \
\
-drive file=edk2-aarch64-code.fd,if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on \
-drive file=ubuntu-os.qcow2,if=virtio \
\
-nographic \
\
-net nic,model=rtl8139 \
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
\
-fsdev local,id=projects,path=/Users/cdf/Projects,security_model=none \
-device virtio-9p-pci,fsdev=projects,mount_tag=projects
```

This starts up a very simple ubuntu machine, works great I can forward ports.

the only thing I can't get right is how to share a folder as you can see above I'm trying:

```
-fsdev local,id=projects,path=/Users/cdf/Projects,security_model=none \
-device virtio-9p-pci,fsdev=projects,mount_tag=projects
```

on the instance, I have created an entry in `/etc/fstab` to mount `projects`

```
projects /home/cdf/projects 9p trans=virtio 0 0
```

and this seems to be working... to a point

I can access the share, however I can't write changes to the share:

```
cdf@ubuntu:~$ ll ./projects
ls: ./projects: Network dropped connection on reset
ls: ./projects/.: Network dropped connection on reset
ls: ./projects/yoco: Network dropped connection on reset
ls: ./projects/cdf: Network dropped connection on reset
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  4 503 dialout  128 Mar 24 07:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x 14 cdf cdf     4096 Mar 26 18:37 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 503 dialout  128 Mar 24 07:27 cdf/
```

I also wanted to make the owner and group `cdf` like multipass mounts do. I'm not too sure what to do to get the mount to work properly, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on an Intel mac, but I ran into the same "Network dropped connection on reset" errors in trying to mount a 9p volume. For me, adding `version=9p2000.u` to the line in fstab seemed to help. This was based on [a comment in the NixOS issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/108984#issuecomment-842192023). My full /etc/fstab line looks like this:

```
Downloads /home/gsf/Downloads 9p _netdev,trans=virtio,version=9p2000.u,msize=104857600 0 0
```

This is the relevant parameter in my qemu command:

```
-virtfs local,path=/Users/gsf/Downloads,security_model=none,mount_tag=Downloads
```

With `security_model=none` I ended up modifying user and group IDs in the guest to match the host. You may have better luck with `security_model=mapped`. I posted some notes on my setup in a gist at [Ubuntu VM on macOS with QEMU](https://gist.github.com/gsf/c7bb24178700ffcaeab9c100c63264bb).